# Ignoring warnings in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, warnings

I'm a beginner iOS programmer and I guess this is a newbie question.
Are you allowed to ignore warnings when placing views in `storyboard` if the `autolayout` is working as expected - warnings like misplaced view or ambiguous height?

Is the app going to work even if I don't fix the warnings and will that app be published?

Comment: Yes, but your layout may be distorted in some devices.

Comment: But what if the simulator of the devices that I target the app for is showing the layout as I want it? In the simulator for all iphones my app isn't distorted.

Comment: Display of Simulator is not accurate. Must test with actual devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the layout may get distorted on some devices if the warnings are ignored.  The display of the simulator is not accurate and the app must be tested on actual devices.
All credits for the answer go to Raptor for answering in the comments.